# How to set manually the css style from an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to chage the css style just after to get successful.

I have the following code but It doesn't work:

```
<style>
  #byDeafult .has-success .input-group-addon {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-color: #ccc;
  }
</style>

<span id="span1WidthExpMap" class="input-group-addon">X:</span>
<input id="inputWidthExpMap" type="text" class="form-control">
<span id="span2WidthExpMap" class="input-group-addon">px</span>

<script>
  $('span1WidthExpMap').addClass('byDeafult');
  $('inputWidthExpMap').addClass('byDeafult');
  $('span2WidthExpMap').addClass('byDeafult');
</script>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: you should use `#` for `$('#span1WidthExpMap')`

Comment: And you should spell default correctly

Answer (score 2):

You need to prefix `#` for ID of element, see [ID Selector (“#id”)] (http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$('#span1WidthExpMap').addClass('byDeafult');
```

Additionally, You have defined your CSS class as `#byDeafult` you need to define it as `.byDeafult`

Also its better wrap your code in [$(document).ready()](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler

```css
  .byDeafult {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-color: #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span id="span1WidthExpMap" class="input-group-addon">X:</span>
<input id="inputWidthExpMap" type="text" class="form-control">
<span id="span2WidthExpMap" class="input-group-addon">px</span>

<script>
  $('#span1WidthExpMap').addClass('byDeafult');
  $('#inputWidthExpMap').addClass('byDeafult');
  $('#span2WidthExpMap').addClass('byDeafult');
</script>
```

Comment: and... document.ready

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira, Since he is defining his script after element, document-ready is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery id selector `#` for an object

```
<script>

     $(function () {
     $('#span1WidthExpMap').addClass('byDeafult');
     $('#inputWidthExpMap').addClass('byDeafult');
     $('#span2WidthExpMap').addClass('byDeafult');
});
</script>
```

Comment: @soul thank you and Sorry for the spelling mistakes  :)